# Putting php inside an echo php shortcode

Tags: php

I am using wordpress. I am using the plugin social locker.

I have figured out how to display the shortcode via PHP:

`<?php echo do_shortcode('[sociallocker id="3071"]  My content Here [/sociallocker]'); ?>`

However I want to display this button that will allow for a print popup in between there.

This code is:

`<?php if ( function_exists( 'pdf_print_popup' ) ) pdf_print_popup(); ?>`

So my question is can I do this:

`<?php echo do_shortcode('[sociallocker id="3071"]  <?php if ( function_exists( 'pdf_print_popup' ) ) pdf_print_popup(); ?>   [/sociallocker]'); ?>`

If not what do I need to do? My goal is to make it so the social locker dissapears once the user shares and they see the print button.

Thanks Guys :)

Comment: My guess is that you need to write your own shortcode but the details depend on the plugin.

Answer (score 2):

You're close but not quite.

**`do_shortcode` expects a string** so give it one!

---

If `function()` returns a string you can

```
echo do_shortcode( '[shortcode]' . function() . '[/shortcode]' );
```

---

If `function()` directly outputs, you can capture its output using output buffering

```
//start the buffer
ob_start();

function();  //i.e pdf_print_popup();

//store out output buffer
$string = ob_get_contents();

//clear the buffer and close it
ob_end_clean();
```

and then use the string we stored

```
echo do_shortcode( '[shortcode]' . $string . '[/shortcode]' );
```